# How to migrate data between Apache Pulsar clusters?

Tags: apache-pulsar

How do folks migrate data between Pulsar environments either for disaster recovery or blue-green deployment are they copying data to a new AWS region or K8S namespace?

Comment: What kind of blue-green deployments are you referring to?

Comment: Trying to upgrade a cluster say from 2.6.x to 2.7.x?

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest approaches is to rely on geo-replication to replicate the data across different clusters.

Comment: Is it possible for an issue in one cluster to put the other clusters at risk when the clusters are in a geo-replicated configuration?

Comment: The design is to compartmentalize the cluster dependencies to max extent in order to avoid so.

Answer (score 1):

This PIP was just created to address this exact scenario of blue-green deployments and to address issues with a cluster becoming non-functioning or corrupted in case an upgrade or update (perhaps of experimental setting changes) goes wrong: https://github.com/pkumar-singh/pulsar/wiki/PIP-95:-Live-migration-of-producer-consumer-or-reader-from-one-Pulsar-cluster-to-another

Until then, aside from using geo-replication, another potential way around this is having an active-active setup (with two live clusters) with a DNS endpoint that producers and consumers use that can be cut over from the old cluster to the new cluster just before taking the old cluster goes down. If it's not acceptable to have the blip in latency this approach would cause, you could replicate just the ingest topics from the old cluster to the new cluster, cut over your consumers, and then cut over your producers. Depending on how your flows are designed, you may need to replicate additional topics to make that happen. Keep in mind that on the cloud there can be different cost implications depending on how you do this. (Network traffic across regions is typically much more expensive than traffic within a single zone.)

If you want to have the clusters completely separate (meaning avoiding using Pulsar geo-replication), you can splice a Pulsar replicator function into each of your flows to manually produce your messages to the new cluster until the traffic is cut over. If you do that, just be mindful that the function must have its own subscription on each topic you deploy it to ensure that you're not losing messages.